# How to extract ramdisk.img

Tags: android, rom

use ubuntu

I type **file ramdisk.img** and the Terminal display **ramdisk.img**: data,
I use `cpio` and get nothing extracted!
How can I `extract` such **ramdisk.img**?

Answer (score 13):

It's highly possible that **ramdisk.img** actually is a compressed file **ramdisk.cpio.gz**. To extract it use this commands:

```
cd /Path/To/Folder/With/ramdisk.cpio.gz/File
mkdir temp_directory && cd temp_directory
gunzip -c ../ramdisk.img | cpio -idm
```

Check this blog post for more info: http://blog.djodjo.org/?p=536

Answer (score 1):

you can mount images:

```
mkdir ~/img_mnt
mount -t udf filename.img ~/img_mnt -o loop
```

Comment: it might need sudo, but depends on the env

Answer (score 0):

Just use p7-zip which is 7z just for POSIX.

```
7z e ramdisk.e RamdiskExtracted
```

I'm not sure about repacking and keeping metadata though.

I guess you could mount it as rw??